# Built a custom component that I want to use as a library but need XML layouts inside

Tags: android, jar, components

I wrote a small platform supporting panels that can be interchanged by a "toolbar".

I want to be able to export this as a custom component through JAR or something similar, but i need to have the XML layouts inside.

Is is possible? If yes, what is the best way?

Thanks in advance.
JQCorreia

Answer (score 0):

Use an Android library project, either [inside of Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject) or [outside](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html#SettingUpLibraryProject).